# Can a report parameter label have more than one value in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-2017

I have a parameter that has it's values and labels:
Lithuania, Baltics, Europe 1, Europe 2, Europe 3, Europe 4, Europe 5 and ALL as null 
[SSRS parameter Labels and Values](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bqZ4P.png)

How can I add a new label that has more than one of those values, for example:
ALL Europe Export with a value of (Europe 1, Europe 2, Europe 3)
[Parameter Labels and Values with the new Label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6TBqz.png)

Is there a way to to add a label with multiple values in SSRS or should it be done in SQL Management Studio?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have found a way through the query/procedure:

`WHERE ((@area = 'ALL EUROPE EXPORT' and a.Area in ('Baltics', 'Europe 1', 'Europe 2', 'Europe 3', 'Europe 4', 'Europe 5')) or (@area = 'LITHUANIA' and a.Area = 'Lithuania') or (@area = 'BALTICS' and a.Area = 'Baltics') or (@area = 'EUROPE 1' and a.Area = 'Europe 1') or (@area = 'EUROPE 2' and a.Area = 'Europe 2') or (@area = 'EUROPE 3' and a.Area = 'Europe 3') or (@area = 'EUROPE 4' and a.Area = 'Europe 4') or (@area = 'EUROPE 5' and a.Area = 'Europe 5') or @area is null)`

And then in parameter values I added all those upper case names.

Answer (score 0):

I would just create multiple report parameters that are dependent on each other.
First parameter is continent (e.g. Europe).  The 2nd parameters would be region (europe1, europe2, baltics...), and the 3rd would be the country. The list of values in your 2nd parameter you can make dynamic based on what has been selected in the first parameter.  And the same for the 3rd parameter.

To define the hierarchy between them you can create a table in your database (table with 3 columns).